# c++ pointer to pointer and call function that receive pointer to pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

The question is how to call function that request `pointer to pointer` if we are already at the function that operate with `pointer to pointer`. I tried some variants but all of them compile with error (SIGSEGV) http://rextester.com/ZSW68923

```
void test_sessiontwo ( int **ptr_to_ptr )
{
    std::cout << *ptr_to_ptr;    
}

void test_session ( int **ptr_to_ptr )
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world2!\n" << *ptr_to_ptr;    
    **ptr_to_ptr = 20;
     test_sessiontwo   ( ptr_to_ptr ); // ERROR. HOW TO CALL THIS???
}

int main()
{
    int* ptr_int;
    *ptr_int = 10;
    test_session ( &ptr_int );   

    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
}
```

Comment: I don't think I'll ever get why people tag C++ questions as C...

Comment: @DrewMcGowen when submitting a question, SO always suggests C when you tag C++, &vv.

Comment: Do you see something wrong with this? `int* ptr_int; *ptr_int = 10;` If you don't then hold off trying to tackle `**` and concentrate on the basics of pointers.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen it was suggestion from stackoverflow

Comment: Your code does not compile with a SIGSEGV error. Your code compiled absolutely fine. SIGSEGV occurs at runtime when you try to access memory that is not yours.

Comment: @abrahab just because SO suggests a tag doesn't mean it's always right - this *clearly* isn't C

Comment: @DrewMcGowen the most important that I correctly wrote at the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code segment

```
   int* ptr_int;
    *ptr_int = 10;
```

is already wrong. Pointer ptr_int was not initialized. So the program has undefined behaviour.

To test your code you could write for example

```
int main()
{
    int* ptr_int = new int( 10 );
    test_session ( &ptr_int );   

    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";

    delete ptr_int;
}
```

Comment: thanks :) work fine. I hesitated about `test_sessiontwo` call :) seems it's ok. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
int i=10;
int *ptr_int = &i;
test_session(&ptr_int);
```

Comment: and why not just `test_session(&i);`?

Comment: @40two Because `&i` is a pointer to `int` not a pointer to pointer to `int`.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious OK, my bad I just saw that `test_session` takes a double pointer.

Comment: @40two the question was about double pointer from the start.. and call to other double pointer function from the first one